# Table valued Parameters equivalent in db2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to pass a collection of Employee objects from Java code to a DB2 Stored Procedure. In SQL server I can do that by making use of Table-Valued Parameters. In DB2 how can  I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Invoking stored procedures with ARRAY of ROW parameters in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjv00002.html).
Or use Declared Global Temporary Table creating it and inserting rows into it beforehand and use this DGTT in your SP as ordinary table.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was about to consider an alternative of passing Json from java and parsing the same in DB2 using Json_Table function..

Comment: Sure, the same is possible passing clob/xml as parameter and using `xmltable` function inside.